# Dynamic data range in Libreoffice calc

Tags: diagram, libreoffice, calc

I have a diagram which is using `***$Einkauf.$B$3:$B210***` as data range (Bereich für Y-Werte/area for y-values).
Can i use some formula here?

How can i make **`210`** dynamic? I want to replace it with the value of cell **`U2`**.

So that i don't have to replace all 210s manually when i get more data in the future, e.g. 300.

Here a screenshot of my diagram:

[image: Screnshot of the diagram]

Comment: Did you try to use the function `ADRESSE()`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
But i think it's not possible to put any formula here.
Not even simple stuff like "=$U3".

Comment: Hallo @KarlH.have you thought about using a macro?  INDIRECT("$U$2") Cell U2 holds the reference cell. 1) start a macro 2) create chart 3) add INDIRECT("$U$2") and test. Tschüss